# Wild card search is not working for Regarding Entity for New Note button on home screen of Dynamics 365 app

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales, dynamics365-app-mobile

I am using updated Dynamics 365 app in my mobile (IOS).

Once you log in, home page appear with **Today** view by default. There is a new button introduced in bottom is **New Note**.
Once you click on the New Note button, it asks for Select Regarding Entity.
My issue is that this searching capability is not working with wild character (*) like star but it works with specified character.

Is this bug/ feature or there is any settings that I am not aware?